# When Clicking on an UISearchController, having it navigate to a new UIView Pragmatically Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

With the typical UISearchController, it only shows another view controller when you actually hit search. I am attempting to get another UIView to appear as soon as you click on the search bar. Any thoughts on how this could be done completely Pragmatically?
I assume it can be accomplished by calling a function when UISearchController.active == true, but have yet to figure it out.

Apps that implement this sort of search function include the Ebay app and Instgram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UISearchController has a property called searchBar. That’s a UISearchBar. UISearchBar has a delegate property that should conform to the UISearchBarDelegate protocol. In that protocol there’s a method searchBarShouldBeginEditing that will be called when the user begins editing in the search field. See:

[Apple’s documentation for searchBarShouldBeginEditing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624306-searchbarshouldbeginediting)